# loud clunking/banging noise coming from the front of my car

Tags: steering

I'm hearing a clunking/banging noise from the front of my car when i steer left or right whilst stationary. Any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: Probably something with the steering linkage, but hard to tell with the lack of information.